# Getting type error in redux in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to store the boolean value of is phone number verified or not.

In my login component:

```
await dispatch(setOTPVerified(data.is_phone_verified));
```

Action.tsx:

```
export const OTP_VERIFIED = 'OTP_VERIFIED';
export const setOTPVerified = (OTPVerified: boolean) => {
  return {
    type: OTP_VERIFIED,
    OTPVerified,
  };
};
```

Reducer.tsx:

```
export interface ExtrasParams {
  OTPVerified?: any;
}

const initialData: ExtrasParams = {
    OTPVerified: false,
  };

const extrasReducer = (state = initialData, action: any): ExtrasParams => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case OTP_VERIFIED:
        state = {...state, OTPVerified: action.OTPVerified};
        return state;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Saga.tsx:

```
function* getOTPVerified(action: any) {
  yield put({
    OTPVerified: action.OTPVerified,
  });
}

export default function* extrasSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(OTP_VERIFIED, getOTPVerified);
}
```

Error in console:

```
Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
The above error occurred in task getOTPVerified
    created by takeLatest(OTP_VERIFIED, getOTPVerified)
```

I am new to using typescript in react native, and not very clear with declaring types in redux. I have been trying different types, but I am not able to clear this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. The effect creator [put(action)](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction) accepts redux action which has below interface:

```
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}
```

redux [dispatch(action)](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) doc says:

> Actions must have a `type` field that indicates the type of action being performed.

From the [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/c21ac204e8ef1d6d428ee3b906b3646c73aa9441/src/createStore.ts#L247), we can see the parameter validation of `dispatch()` method.

```js
if (typeof action.type === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error(
    'Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant.'
  )
}
```

You **MUST** provide a `type` field for the action object. Something like this:

```
function* getOTPVerified(action: any) {
  yield put({
    type: 'OTP_VERIFIED_SUCCESS',
    OTPVerified: action.OTPVerified,
  });
}
```

Comment: After making these changes, I am not getting any error but my application does not go to next screen

Comment: @pratteekshaurya If you have a new question, please create a new post.